# annotationView callout transparent in iOS 13

Tags: mapkit, ios13, mkannotation

[image: callout in iOS 13]Screen shot above shows annotationView callouts in my app appearing transparent in iOS 13.  The app is currently in the store, and has been for many years.  The last code change was March of 2018, and testing in simulator and on device (using direct usb connection) do not show this problem as seen below:

[image: callout in iOS 12]

I have added the proper device support files to version of Xcode used to submit the app in March 2018 so I could build/run the app on a device running ios13 - annotationView callouts work as expected! But using same device and the version of the app from the app store, annotationView callouts show transparent.

Also tested the latest app store version of the app on devices running iOS 9 though iOS 12 and as expected, annotationView callouts work as they should.

I have deleted and reinstalled app via the app store on an iOS 13 device - problem persists.

I'm looking for ideas on how to track down this phenomena.  I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: Is the iOS 13 device you are testing on using Dark Mode?

Comment: Good idea!  It was in dark mode, so I deleted the app, rebooted the device, installed app from app store and  ...... .... ......  Problem still persists.  Dang!

Comment: I’m assuming you’ve solved this by now. If so, feel free to [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If not, please share enough for us to reproduce the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be that in the current iPad OS (13.4) this error is fixed by apple.

[image: Screenshot 13.4]